# Netbeans + Mercurial Graphical Diff

Tags: netbeans, mercurial

New to Netbeans (6.9.1) and Mercurial (1.7.5) (our company doesn't believe in open source software), I am specifically trying to get NetBeans' "Show History" command to work. Viewing this website, [NetBeans <3 Mercurial](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2009/11/10/netbeans--hearts--mercurial----with-screenshots.html), this looks like it should be simple. Make at least two commits, go to "Team -> [Mercurial ->] Show History" and you should see side-by-side changes. However, in both side-by-side screens within my NetBeans, all it says is .

On the other hand, if I use the command-line, typing "hg diff -r 3:4 file.htm", for instance, I get a valid diff. "hg diff --rev 4 file.htm" also gives a valid diff against the local, non-committed, changes.

Within NetBeans, "Local History" works quite well, but when I right-click, Mercurial -> Diff, the "Base" file on the left shows nothing - I'm assuming this is the latest committed file - while the local version on the right shows up.

My question: Is NetBeans set up correctly to work with Mercurial (it seems to be correct in all other cases), is Mercurial itself incorrectly set up (this seems like a hard thing to mess up), or is this a case of user-error?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that since we don't have admin rights (our company is crazy), and access to C:\Program Files is messy, Mercurial was unable to work exactly as needed within NetBeans. Re-installing Mercurial under C:\ and pointing NetBeans there remedied this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using NetBeans as well. One *gotcha* I noticed, when you do Mercurial operations, it only shows you results based on your selection in your project tree.

Try selecting the root "Source Files" in your project tree and then see if there is a difference when you run the command.